# Create JSON string by reverting a PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, json

Basically I'm starting with a JSON formatted string. An example of this string is:
 `[{"options":[{"valid":true,"content":"Answer"}],"content":"Question1","type":"text"},{"options":[{"valid":false,"content":"Answer"}],"content":"Question2","type":"radios"}]` 
With `json_decode` I'm converting it into an array that looks like this in this example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [options] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [valid] => 1
                            [content] => Answer
                        )

                )

            [content] => Question1
            [type] => text
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [options] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [valid] => 
                            [content] => Answer
                        )

                )

            [content] => Question2
            [type] => radios
        )

)
```

And storing this in MySQL using this PHP code:

```
$questions = json_decode($_POST['test']);

        $con=mysqli_connect("Localhost","root","","test");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        foreach( $questions as $question ){
            $options = $question->options;
            $options_id = array();
            $question_query = "INSERT INTO `question` (Content, Type) VALUES ('{$question->content}', '{$question->type}')";
            echo $question_query;
            if( !mysqli_query($con, $question_query) ){ echo mysqli_error($con);}
            $question_id= mysqli_insert_id($con);
            echo $question_id;
            foreach($options as $option){
            $options_query = "INSERT INTO `option` (Question_id, Content) VALUES ({$question_id}, '{$option->content}')";
            echo $options_query;
            if( !mysqli_query($con, $options_query) ){
            echo mysqli_error($con);
      }
  }
```

It's just storing questions and it's possible answers.

So at some point I will need to this process backwards (take the information from MySQL and building the JSON again so I can render the corresponding UI). Is there a way to just revert this code and do the process backwards? Maybe with `json_enconde`?

Comment: json is simply a string representation of a javascript data structure (a simple int/string up to arrays/objects). You don't "reverse" the process. You suck data out of the database, build a PHP data structure, then encode THAT into json.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for the explanation, I was a bit confused in the subject. So in this particular case, how do you think I could build the PHP data structure?

Comment: you've got your var_dump of it, which shows you exactly what the structure was. work from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking something like below

```
$a = '[{"options":[{"valid":true,"content":"Answer"}],"content":"Question1","type":"text"},{"options":[{"valid":false,"content":"Answer"}],"content":"Question2","type":"radios"}]' ;
$b = json_decode($a,true);
//print_r($b);

foreach($b as $key=>$val){
    echo 'Content : '.$val['content'];
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'Type : '.$val['type'];
    echo '<br />';
    foreach($val['options'] as $key1=>$val1){
        echo 'Valid :'.$val1['valid'];
        echo '<br />';
        echo 'Answer : '.$val1['content'];
        echo '<br />';

    }
    echo '<hr><br />';
}
```

The output will look like

```
Content : Question1
Type : text
Valid :1
Answer : Answer
------------------------------------------------------
Content : Question2
Type : radios
Valid :
Answer : Answer
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but no, what I'm looking for is code to retrieve data from MySQL and build the `JSON` again using PHP. In my code I decoded the JSON, now I want to encode it back.

Comment: Ok I see your mysql data is json encodeded so you may get the original json as 

$b = json_decode({data from mysql},true);
$final_data = json_encode($b);

Hope this helps.